# How can I display which item inside of an array of objects the user has clicked on using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

I'm trying to display the `OfferName` upon user clicking on a list of images that each have their own data (an array of objects) using jQuery.  I've achieved this using plain JS but I want to know how to achieve this with jQuery.

How can I make it so that upon user clicking on the image, the individual and correct `OfferName` appears in the console? This one confused me a lot even though I tried reverse engineering the plain JS :(.

We can assume the array of objects looks like this below:

```
var offers = [ {
    id: 5933,
    desc: "game",
    OfferName: "blitz",
    Template: "nonfeatured",
    SortIndex: 0
  }, {
    id: 5934,
    desc: "game",
    OfferName: "blitz  - 2",
    Template: "featured",
    SortIndex: 0
  }, {
    id: 5935,
    desc: "game",
    OfferName: "blitz  - 3",
    Template: "special",
    SortIndex: 0
  }];

  $(".items").on("click", function () {
    var offerName = "";

    for(var i = 0; i < offers.length; i++) {
        offerName = offers[i].OfferName;
        $(this).on("click", function (offerName) {
            console.log("user clicked " + offerName);
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: You're trying to map a list of stuff in code to a list of stuff in html. If you're building your html from the offers array, you should include that code in your question. If you're not, you should build your html from the offers array.

Comment: @CharlesBamford hey Charles, thanks for your input.  I just want to grab the value the user has clicked on, I'm not trying to do anything html wise.

Comment: There needs to be some relationship between `offers` and the things with class `.items` for your code to work reliably. I'm not seeing how that relationship can be determined as posted in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you're building your HTML, but you can accomplish your goal using [data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) and [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Here's an example

```js
var offers = [{
  id: 5933,
  desc: "game",
  OfferName: "blitz",
  Template: "nonfeatured",
  SortIndex: 0
}, {
  id: 5934,
  desc: "game",
  OfferName: "blitz  - 2",
  Template: "featured",
  SortIndex: 0
}, {
  id: 5935,
  desc: "game",
  OfferName: "blitz  - 3",
  Template: "special",
  SortIndex: 0
}];

offers.forEach(o => {
  let t = `<div class='tpl item' data-offername='${o.OfferName}' data-id='${o.id}'>Click on this if you're interested in ${o.OfferName}</div>`;
  $('.container').append(t);
})

$(document).on("click", ".item", function() {
  console.log(`user clicked: ${$(this).data('offername')}, id: ${$(this).data('id')}`);
})
```

```css
.item {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'></div>
```